# Check if DIV is visible using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i needed to hide a div on my code behind:

```
bool hideDiv = false
//codes to change hideDiv
myDiv.visible = hideDiv;
```

and i want to check visibility of my div using javascript:

```
if (jQuery("myDiv") != null){
    //some codes
}
else{
    //some codes
}
```

and the 'jQuery("myDiv")' is always not null (even if the div was actually not visible), what is the better way to check if a div is visible?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) inside [`is` filtering function](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if ($('#myDiv').is(':visible'))
```

Notes:

- You probably forgot the `#` before the id in your selector(`jQuery("myDiv")`).
- jQuery will never return null no matter if the searched elements exist or not, unlike `document.getElementById`

Comment: hmmm, unfortunately, still the same, i've tried your code if ($('#myDiv').is(':visible')), and i've tried my code with additional "#"  if (jQuery("#myDiv") != null). still as if it is always visible

Comment: @Eytch, this code is perfectly valid and works, it seems like you have problem somewhere else or that your div isn't hidden, check it with: `$('#myDiv').is(':hidden')`

Comment: i ended up using document.getElementById("MainContent_myDiv") :)

Comment: @Eytch, Dear lord, so your id isn't `myDiv`! use this: `$('#MainContent_myDiv').is(':visible')`